# numpy 2D array: get indices of all entries that are connected and share the same value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indices

I have a 2D numpy Array filled with integer-values from 0 to N, how can i get the indices of all entries that are directly connected and share the same value.

Addition: Most of the entries are zero and can be ignored!

Example Input array:

```
[ 0 0 0 0 0 ]
[ 1 1 0 1 1 ]
[ 0 1 0 1 1 ]
[ 1 0 0 0 0 ]
[ 2 2 2 2 2 ]
```

Wished output indices:

```
1: [ [1 0] [1 1] [2 1] [3 0] ] # first 1 cluster
   [ [1 3] [1 4] [2 3] [2 4] ] # second 1 cluster

2: [ [4 0] [4 1] [4 2] [4 3] [4 4] ] # only 2 cluster
```

the formating of the output arrays is not important, i just need separated value clusters where it is possible to address the single indices

What i was first thinking of is:

```
N = numberClusters
x = myArray

for c in range(N):
   for i in np.where(x==c):
         # fill output array with i
```

but this misses the separation of clusters that have the same value

Comment: connected means 'on the same row' ?

Comment: with connected i mean that they "touch" each other either in x,y or diagonal coordinates. Have a look at the example how i clustered the "ones", i hope this makes it clear.

Comment: Look for `connected components labeling algorithm` implementation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`skimage.measure.label`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.label) (install it with `pip install scikit-image`, if needed) for this:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import measure

# Setup some data
np.random.seed(42)
img = np.random.choice([0, 1, 2], (5, 5), [0.7, 0.2, 0.1])
# [[2 0 2 2 0]
#  [0 2 1 2 2]
#  [2 2 0 2 1]
#  [0 1 1 1 1]
#  [0 0 1 1 0]]

# Label each region, considering only directly adjacent pixels connected
img_labeled = measure.label(img, connectivity=1)
# [[1 0 2 2 0]
#  [0 3 4 2 2]
#  [3 3 0 2 5]
#  [0 5 5 5 5]
#  [0 0 5 5 0]]

# Get the indices for each region, excluding zeros
idx = [np.where(img_labeled == label)
       for label in np.unique(img_labeled)
       if label]
# [(array([0]), array([0])),
#  (array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2]), array([2, 3, 3, 4, 3])),
#  (array([1, 2, 2]), array([1, 0, 1])),
#  (array([1]), array([2])),
#  (array([2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4]), array([4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3]))]

# Get the bounding boxes of each region (ignoring zeros)
bboxes = [area.bbox for area in measure.regionprops(img_labeled)]
# [(0, 0, 1, 1),
#  (0, 2, 3, 5),
#  (1, 0, 3, 2),
#  (1, 2, 2, 3),
#  (2, 1, 5, 5)]
```

The bounding boxes can be found using the very helpful function [`skimage.measure.regionprops`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#regionprops), which contains a plethora of information on the regions. For the bounding box it returns a tuple of `(min_row, min_col, max_row, max_col)`, where pixels belonging to the bounding box are in the half-open interval `[min_row; max_row)` and `[min_col; max_col)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168730/discussion-between-gustavz-and-graipher).

Comment: how can I achieve to additionally get the class that is assigned to the bounding box? Because when I take the class that is assigned to the box coordinates I mostly get background as the x,y min max values normally don’t lie on the object

Comment: @GustavZ Which label? The value that is in the original array? You can use `[img[i][0] for i in idx]` for that. If you want the label that is given by the labelling, you can use `[area.label for area in measure.regionprops(img_labeled)]`.

Comment: yes exactly what `[img[i][0] for i in idx]` does, but that just gives me all the labels that are in the current image (like classification), but i want to find the exact label for each bounding box that i compute with `boxes = [area.bbox for area in measure.regionprops(map_labeled)]`  (like detection)

How would i do that? Because right now i just assume thhat in the middle of the box should be the object and i take that label...

Comment: @GustavZ See my comment above: `[area.label for area in measure.regionprops(img_labeled)]`.

Comment: you mean `[area.label for area in measure.regionprops(img_labeled)]`? that does the same with the only difference that it is the label generated by `skimage`.

But what i want is the following: my original `image` is a segmentation map, where all pixels are class labels, and after computing the box for each cluster i also want the label for each cluster.... excuse me if you already answered that, but i dont see where

Comment: @GustavZ You are right, that I did not answer yet. I'll get back to you once I'm no longer on mobile.

Comment: nevermind i got it. with `area.coords` i can address the right pixels :)
thanks!

Comment: @GustavZ Yes, I was just experimenting with that as well.