# Is there a way to replicate scikit.measure.label for edge detection in Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I know this is a frivolous question, but is there a way to replicate that functionality without using the scikit library?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49771746/numpy-2d-array-get-indices-of-all-entries-that-are-connected-and-share-the-same) is essentially what I'm trying to do. As far as I've gotten is possibly using the concept of neighbors via a meta array, but I'm still struggling with the idea of how to split that into different arrays for each set of neighbors.

Edit: Sorry haven't asked many questions here, realized this is difficult without actual examples.

E.g. Given the numpy array:

```
[ 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 ]
```

I'm trying to get to an output that's two different arrays with the index location of the touching values (excluding 0's). So desired result is:

```
output1 = [[0,2], [0,3], [1,2], [2,2], [2,3]]
output2 = [[4,1], [4,2], [4,3], [5,1], [5,2]]
```

Edit #2: I've made some progress. I am now able to create a list of lists. Here is the code:

```
data = np.asarray(image_x)
vals = np.argwhere(data == 0)
list = []
listoflists = []
row = -1
for x in range(0, vals.shape[0]):
    for y in range(0, vals.shape[1]-1):
        if row == -1:
            row = vals[x][0]
        if row == vals[x][0]:
            list.append(vals[x][1])
        else:
            listoflists.append((vals[x-1][0], list))
            row = vals[x][0]
            list = []
            list.append(vals[x][1])
```

Notes:

- `image_x` is a black and white image of shape outlines
- The loop currently doesn't capture a pixel if it is a single pixel on a single row at the very end. I'm troubleshooting this now, just wanted to post the update in my excitement.

Comment: `how to split that into different arrays for each set of neighbors` isn't too clear. Can you add minimal sample data and expected output?

Comment: Sorry about that, I've added an example in an edit.

Comment: So, using `scikit.measure.label` is allowed?

Comment: No unfortunately not. I'm trying to do this only with numpy. I believe `numpy.argwhere` will be key. However I'm having trouble coming up with a statement that will separate multiple groupings. I'm thinking some mutation of a sort algorithm. Where I create new arrays and iterate through the results of `numpy.argwhere` then sort them based on a neighbor "match". Implementation advice on creating that undefined number of potential arrays would go a long way though

Comment: When you write `scikit`, do you actually mean `skimage`?  (That's the actual importable name for `scikit-image`.)

Comment: Are you also ruling out using `scipy`?  `scipy` has a `label` function in [`scipy.ndimage.label`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.label.html).

Comment: Yeah I'm ruling out every library other than `numpy`. `numpy.argwhere` gets us most of the way there. It returns every x,y coordinate that we're looking for. Now I just need to sort them into unique arrays based on which are neighbors. I've thought about putting them all into arrays based on unique row, then chunking based on gaps there. Then merging the rows based on neighboring rows that have valid values within +-1. But I can't figure out how to create an array of arrays where both of those will require appending unknown length arrays.

Comment: Posted an update! Almost there!